# SSL Cert for RD Gateway is missing the AD subdomain. Am I hooped?

Tags: active-directory, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-gateway

I am setting up an RD Gateway server for test purposes and I think I may have screwed up on the SSL Cert purchase.

I have created a subnet (192.168.25.XXX) off our main network with a firewall and server running VMs for the DC, RDS, Workstation, etc.

I have purchased the domain name, configured an external DNS, and I am in the process of configuring the RD Gateway Server. I want to setup an RD Gateway Server /w Office installed in shared activation mode.

The domain is AD.mydomain.com but I purchased the SSL Certificate for remote.mydomain.com without considering that the entire domain is subdomained under AD.mydomain.com

Is there any way that this can be setup without a wildcard cert? Those are a bit expensive for a learning project.

Comment: Just ask them to reissue the certificate with the required name.

Comment: It turns out I was able to set the published name for the RDG to remote.mydomain.com and had missed exporting the private key from IIS to the RDG.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the certificate wasn't fully installed. The RDPublishedName is set to remote.mydomain.com and I exported the certificate from IIS and made sure it was installed on the RD Broker/Licenser/Gateway.

All is working fine now.